# Error - [tsc] Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.2' - while running gulp serve command in SharePoint framework webs solution

Tags: sharepoint, gulp, spfx

I am trying to run gulp serve for SharePointSPFX solution. Surprisingly got this error

> Starting subtask 'tsc'...
> [23:28:59] Error - [tsc] Error: Cannot find module '@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.2'

So I ran npm outdated to check any packages are outdated or not. So I got the result:

| Package | Current | Wanted | Latest | LOCATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.7 | 0.2.3 | 0.2.17 | 0.6.47 | global |
| @types/react-dom | 16.9.8 | 16.9.13 | 17.0.8 | global |
| @types/webpack-env | 1.13.1 | 1.16.0 | 1.16.0 | global |
| ajv | 5.2.5 | 5.5.2 | 8.6.0 | global |

How can I update @microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-3.7 to 0.2.17?

Answer (score 2):

in my case it was because i upgraded my project and missed a step, upgrading the version in `tsconfig.json`

more details here
https://bresleveloper.blogspot.com/2021/07/sfpx-node-saas-error.html

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem.
This blog helped me: https://siddharthvaghasia.com/2019/06/09/how-to-upgrade-spfx-solution-to-latest-version/
If you have problem with just one spfx solution the solution in blog should help.

Also check your global yeoman package:

```
npm ls -g --depth=0 @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
```

Also check global outdated package:

```
npm outdated -g
```